# Cannot create OpenSSH tunnel

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I am trying to setup a vpn via openssh.

I am running the client on Arch Linux. The version of the client is `OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`.

The ssh server is on Ubuntu 17.10 on Google Cloud, version `OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`. In the server configuration I have enabled all kinds of forwarding as well as the `PermitTunnel` option. I have restarted the sshd daemon. I had also disabled `apparmor` just in case. No selinux is running. I also did `modprobe tun` just in case (although openvpn for instance works without issues). The server has ip forwarding enabled on both Google Cloud and Ubuntu level. `ufw` is disabled and the Google firewall is completely opened.

First I tried connecting with this command:

`sudo ssh -i ssh_key  -w any:any root@ip  -vvv -o Tunnel=point-to-point`

The above fails and the debug output from ssh around the point of failure is:

`debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxxxxxx.
debug1: Requesting tun unit 1 in mode 1
debug1: sys_tun_open: tun1 mode 1 fd 4
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0`

As the above failed, I thought I should create the tun devices first. This is what I did:

On the client:
`sudo ip tuntap add tun1 mode tun
sudo ip link set tun1 up
sudo ip addr add 172.32.0.1/24 peer 172.32.0.2 dev tun1`

On the server:

`sudo ip tuntap add tun1 mode tun
sudo ip link set tun1 up
sudo ip addr add 172.32.0.2/24 peer 172.32.0.1 dev tun1`

But this fails again in the same exact way.

I tried running an sshd server on my local machine and connect to localhost. But then again it failed in the same manner.

I tried local port forwarding and it worked.

How can one properly setup a vpn with openssh? I thoroughly searched the net but nothing helped there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem on my Arch Linux. ArchLinux is installed on the client and server. The version of openssh is `7.7p1-1`.
As a temporary solution,  I installed openssh version `7.6p1-2`

Comment: Indeed, it is a bug on the current version (http://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2855).

Comment: Same problem on Arch Linux. Update to openssh 7.7p1-2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with OpenSSH_7.7p1 Debian-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar, 2018.

After  downgrade ssh with this script:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.4p1-10+deb9u3_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-sftp-server_7.4p1-10+deb9u3_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-server_7.4p1-10+deb9u3_amd64.deb
dpkg -i *.deb
systemctl restart ssh
systemctl status ssh
```

VPNs start working again.